# How is MVVM in Xamarin.Forms/UWP/WPF any different from using code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp

In learning Xamarin.Forms/UWP/WPF tutorials always tout MVVM as the design pattern of choice and I've followed suite, but I've never understood why. To contrast, in asp.net MVC the templated framework is used to great effect, Controllers deliver models to the view (HTML of some sort).

But in the Xamarin.Forms/UWP/WPF and others, we create a completely new class, ignore the code-behind file that cannot be removed and relegate it to telling our view where to look when binding data.

The only reason I could think of that makes MVVM better is if we could supply logic where different VM's could be 'injected' into the same view, maybe that would justify it.Though I have no idea how to do that.

Otherwise, how is creating a view model class better than using the code behind file? Is it really worse separation of concerns just because the view and code behind have the same name and are instantiated together?

Comment: Well, then skip the VM and use the code behind for a Xamarin.Forms/UWP/WPF mixed project and find yourself writing duplicated code behind which is also hard to test

Comment: As an example, see https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps and look at the core part which is shared by all platforms. How will you do that with code behind?

Comment: In a connected world where "streams" of data are "observable", how are you going to bind asynchronously and maintain the view state?  Hello Knockout, and other libraries including Angular, and React -- where everything is "reactive", and "responsive" web.  It's all data binding and MVVM now.  We evolved.  You coming?

Comment: Automated testing is one of the reasons. ViewModels provide nice possibility to test most of the view logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVVM pattern is much cleaner than using code-behind.

### Separation of concerns

Imagine you have a view and a code-behind implemented. Now the business comes with a request to completely change the way the controls are presented - replacing them with new controls, changing layout and so on. Chances are, you will be forced to rewrite a lot of code just to satisfy the requirement, because the code-behind is directly tied to the view.

Now in case you have MVVM in place, you can easily swap the `View` part of the equation for any view which utilizes data binding to the right properties in a View model. You could easily present a single View model in several different ways - like **creating multiple different views** for different user roles while the view model stays exactly the same, you just **choose what to display and how**.

What view model actually creates is a middle layer between data and their presentation and makes it possible to more easily transform the data the view uses and change the presentation without affecting the view model if the interface is kept intact.

### Data binding

Also if you are meaning purely code-behind without data-binding, the advantages of MVVM become even clearer. When you have a data-bound property that updates after user input in a `TwoWay` manner, for example if you have a form the user has to fill out, you **don't have to remember to fetch the latest "changes"** from the control using `Text` property, you know the latest version is already there in the data-bound property. In addition, you can add **validation in the property setter**, you can **update other properties** in the setter as well to **orchestrate data handling** in a **much more abstract** way than with code-behind approach, where you are tied to events and having to remember where the data come from and which **specific controls** and which **specific properties** you have to update. Imagine you display a given text in multiple places - with data binding you just set a single property and rely on `{Binding}` to display the text in all bound controls. With code-behind only, you need to remember which concrete controls display the text and when you add a new control, you have to update the code-behind appropriately, which is far less convenient.

### Cross platform development

Another example would be having to develop a cross-platform application with native UI using MvvmCross. Here you can decide that some views or some functionality will not be available for certain OS or that you want to just implement it later. This is entirely possible - you just don't provide the UI for that functionality and the view model can stay the same.

### View state

Finally - having all view state in code-behind means that when you navigate away, you must **store the state** somehow and **restore it** when **navigating back** because a new page is created. With MVVM you may decide to **keep the view models of the navigation stack in memory** and when navigating back just set the `DataContext` of the page to the **existing view model instance** to get back just in the same state as you left off.

Overall I see MVVM as a great pattern to improve flexibility of your codebase and it makes your solution more future-proof and resilient to changes.

Comment: Multiple views for the same view model actually makes a lot of sense and I'm not sure why I didnt think of that. I'm not sure I buy your data binding or cross platform examples as being exclusive to mvvm but I'm going to keep them in mind as I learn. I'd especially like to understand your view state example though. MVVM is not at all required for that, you can navigate  in a frame in MainPage and maintain objects in it's .cs. But it gets really messy if you have a lot of objects tied to other pages, passing them in and out.   Can you explain in more details how this is in done in mvvm?

Comment: Well, if you are using UWP and don't set page's NavigationCacheMode to Required, then the page is actually disposed of when the user navigates forward and created again when navigated back. Here the problem is that the navigation frame only maintains the navigation parameter, but not the data. For example if the page loaded some data from a web service, it and then display them, it would have to be queried again after navigating forward and back, which is inefficient. With View Models maintained in the navigation stack (as MvvmLight, MvvmCross or Prism all do), the ViewModels

Comment: Stay in memory and are only attached to the page via datacontext right after navigation occurs. The page is still created again, but the data are already there in the view model so there is no need to query the service again

Comment: Just as a bonus - I suggest you to check the wonderful Prism Developer Guide, which contains very well written info on MVVM (in the linked 5th chapter) in general and is even full of Best practices in this area. Although it is for WPF the whole thing is worth reading : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx